# defecating on a toilet or in a toilet

Tags: american-english

I've seen both being used, but I am not sure if either one of them is the natural way of putting this silly idea that everyone does. Also, how do you decide between on and in, because both of them can be used in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifically following the word "defecating", these two phrases mean very different things:

Usually you would say that someone is **defecating** ***in*** **the toilet** to mean that they are correctly leaving their waste **within the confines of the toilet bowl**.

Saying that someone is **defecating** ***on*** **the toilet** is more likely to mean that they left waste **on the exterior surface of the toilet**, such that now the toilet must be cleaned.

However, in other contexts the preposition choice is less important. "In the toilet" can mean "within the bowl or tank of the toilet", but it can also mean "inside the bathroom." "On the toilet" can refer to waste left on the surface, but in the context of a person, "on the toilet" means "sitting on the toilet." As such, "Bob is on the toilet" and "Bob is in the toilet" are usually interchangeable.